# Duvidas execução ggplot 2: dados fora de ordem, e barra de erro

Tags: r, ggplot2

Olá. Estou tentando usar o ggplot2 para fazer um gráfico no R. Esse gráfico é um gráfico de barra que trata de várias concentrações (cada concentração tem uma barra) no eixo X, que está associada a uma variável dependente no eixo Y que é a inibição de crescimento parasitário (%).

Porém, encontrei um problema: Ele coloca as concentrações fora de ordem (O certo seria 13,07, depois 6,53, depois 3,26 etc).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que usei

```
library(ggplot2)

comp_1_concentrations = c('13.07','6.53','3.26','1.63','0.81','0.4','0.2')

comp_1_inhibition = c(78,50,28,15,10,2,1.5)

comp_1_desv_pad = c(10,1,10,1.5,10,1,0.2)

data <- data.frame(
  name=comp_1_conc,
  value=comp_1_inhib,
  sd=comp_1_desv
)

ggplot(data) +
  geom_bar( aes(x=name, y=value), stat="identity", fill="black", alpha=1.7,color='black') + 
  geom_errorbar( aes(x=name, ymin=value, ymax=value+sd), width=0.5, colour="black", alpha=0.9, size=0.8)+theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                                                                                                                            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+labs(x = 'Concentrations (µM)')+labs(y = 'Growth inhibition (%)')+labs(title = 'Compound 1')
```

Answer (score 3):

Vamos dividir os problemas.

### 1) Alterar a ordem do eixo X:

Antes de mais nada, uma pequena alteração dos dados que tem a variável `name` como um fator (que introduz alguns problemas que não vão nos ajudar agora). `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, mantém essa variável como texto. Imagino que você as deseje assim.

```
data <- data.frame(
  name=comp_1_concentrations,
  value=comp_1_inhibition,
  sd=comp_1_desv_pad,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Com esses novos dados, vamos ao gráfico. A função `reorder` permite reordenar os valores do primeiro argumento com base nos valores do segundo argumento. Transformando eles em numéricos acredito que assumam a ordem correta.

```
p1 <- ggplot(data) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = reorder(name, as.numeric(name)), y = value), 
           stat = "identity", 
           fill = "black", 
           alpha = 0.7)
p1
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 2) Tirar o grid de fundo

Para fazer isso usamos a função `theme` e seus argumentos. Para entender melhor como funcionam, recomendo sua [documentação](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html).

O argumento `panel.grid` (com suas respectivas divisões em `major` e `minor` e `x` e `y`) controla as grades do fundo. Para eliminá-las devemos atribuir `element_blank()` para ele.

```
p2 <- p1 +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
p2
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 3) Barras de erro

Para que as barra de erro mostrem apenas a parte "positiva" do erro, basta usar o valor, e não `valor - sd` como `ymin`. Assim temos:

```
p2 + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = name, ymin=value, ymax=value+sd), 
                width=0.5, colour="black", 
                alpha=0.9, size=1.3)
```

[image: fig3]

Comment: Obrigado. Há ainda uma forma de deixar a ordem decrescente? Tentei usar o argumento decreasing = TRUE mas não existe para essa função.

Comment: Você pode i) inverter o vetor com a função `rev()` ou ii) reordenar por `-vetor` (`reorder(x, -y)`) - um pequeno _hack_

Comment: Onde extamente coloco esse comando? Em que lugar do código especificamente? Se eu colocar na definição dos vetores (primeiras linhas) ele não muda

Comment: Na primeira geometria. `p + geom_bar(aes(x = reorder(name, -as.numeric(name)), y = value), ...)`